# Lipschitz function with non-lipschitz derivative

Tags: functions, inequality, lipschitz-functions

I tried to find a Counter-example for the following relation for all $x,y\in C$ where $C$is a convex set:

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y|\Rightarrow |f'(x)-f'(y)|\leq \beta|x-y|$$

Is it possible to find a function which is lipschitz but its derivative is not lipschitz?

The converse is not true for example derivative of $f(x)=x^2$ is lipschitz but the function itself is not lipschitz.

Comment: $f(x)= \sqrt{x}$ on [0. 1].

Comment: @Mustafa_Said https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Examples                  
$\sqrt{x}$ is **not** Lipschitz continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I suppose you want $f'$ to exist everywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that $x\sqrt{x}$ is Lipschitz continuous on $[0,1]$, because its derivative is bounded on $[0,1]$.

However, its derivative $\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{x}$ is not Lipschitz continuous on $[0,1]$, because the derivative of this function gets unboundedly large as we let $x\downarrow 0$.

Comment: If $g$ is continuous and bounded but not Lipschitz-continuous (e.g. $g(x)=\sqrt {|x|}$  for $|x|\leq 1$ and $g(x)=1$ for $|x|>1$) let $f(x)=\int_0^xg(t)dt$ for $x\in \Bbb R$.......+1