# $C^\infty$ Lipschitz function with non-Lipschitz derivative

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $F \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R}^d)$ be smooth and Lipschitz continuous. Is it true that $\nabla F$ is also Lipschitz continuous? The answer is negative if we only assume $F$ to be $C^1$ (see [Lipschitz function with non-lipschitz derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572117/lipschitz-function-with-non-lipschitz-derivative)), but what about smooth functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is still negative for smooth maps.

Consider $f(x)=\frac{\cos(x^2) +1}{2}$, $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \ dt$

You have

$$\begin{cases}
F^\prime(x) &= f(x) = \frac{\cos(x^2) +1}{2}\\
F^{\prime \prime}(x) &= -x \sin(x^2)
\end{cases}$$

$F^\prime$ is bounded, hence $F$ is Lipschitz. However $F^{\prime \prime}$ is unbounded and $F^\prime$ not Lipschitz. And $F$ is a smooth map.

Comment: Thank you. I guess you could even take $F$ as the counter-example: Lipschitz since $F' = f$ is bounded, but $f$ is not Lipschitz since $f' = x\cos(x)$ is unbounded?

Comment: That's right! Why make it complicated when it can be simple! I'll update my answer.